# Output line breaks in browser using CSS

Tags: css

Wrapped in a `<pre>` element, line breaks are rendered in the browser and the use of `<br/>` tags is not necessary. Is it possible to achieve the same effect by applying CSS to a `<div>` element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSS property

```
white-space: pre;
```

will achieve this for you. Note that there are other similar values for this property which may be a better solution for your need, so check out the documentation.

Ref: [CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-prop), [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#white-space)